# How to lock a Linux/Debian/KDE system to one program (a password-protected kiosk mode for Kodi)?

Tags: debian, security, kde, kiosk, kodi

I'd like to lock my Debian10/KDE system to one program and prevent any interaction of a user with anything beyond the always-on-top fullscreen program, making it impossible to shut down, to minimize, to open the process manager and to show the tray bar by pressing the Windows key.

In particular I'd like to lock it to the media center Kodi in a way that closing/minimizing it or opening other software requires the root password. (This would also require the root-password for the shutdown button within Kodi or at least e.g. a custom key-combination).

Is this possible with some software or CLI commands / parameters *within the current session* (maybe using [KDE Plasma Activities](https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma#Activities))? And if not how could this get implemented technically?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to run it on top of KDE?

Comment: Seems to me that running your app with simply a Window Manager such as `twm` rather then a Desktop Manager such as KDE would neatly solve most of the issues

Comment: Panos Yes. @roaima How? Could one start only Kodi this way?

Answer (score 1):

`xtrlock` maybe of interest to you. It's transparent / non-obscuring.

Although, it doesn't achieve exactly what you are trying to.

https://packages.debian.org/stable/xtrlock

Comment: Maybe this could be modified so that it still does allow Kodi commands / navigating Kodi (but nothing else).

Comment: Filed a feature-request for it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xtrlock/+bug/1937917

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to configure the `.xsession` to launch the application and either configure the window manager not not allow other applications to be launched or not install a window manager.

For the display manager I used `nodm`

I didn't worry about the user quitting because nodm will restart the session if the user quits.

Comment: Is this possible within the currently running session? And especially if so could you elaborate on how to implement this?

Comment: is what possible? what currently running session? for details install nodm  read the manual, read the manual page for xsession,

Comment: Your solution. The X session; logging out and starting a new session closes all open windows for example which is something I'd like to avoid. Sure, I could read those manuals but if you already implemented this solution it would make it far easier for others to implement if you share some basic example code.

Comment: no, it doesn't. not unless you can exit the only application running "kodi" without closing all the windows,

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [cage](https://github.com/Hjdskes/cage).

It's not yet available in Debian 11 and also [can't be built on it](https://github.com/Hjdskes/cage/issues/226).

However, [it's already in "Debian 12 testing"](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=cage).

I will update this once it's in Debian 11 stable or backports...or once Debian 12 has been released.
Please comment below if you know if/when it'll be available. If dependency [libwlroots10](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/libwlroots10) was available in Debian11/backports, it could get installed from the Debian repositories if it was added (but the dependency is only available in Debian 12 bookworm).